# Delayed (timed) unregister sensor listener inside IntentService (WakefulIntentService)

Tags: android, android-sensors, intentservice, commonsware-cwac, sensormanager

I've implemented an `IntentService` which, using `SensorManager`, reads data from a heart rate sensor.

It gets periodically called using `AlarmManager` and a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` and then, upon `onSensorChanged`, it updates Google Fit data by using Fitness History API, using the time of the onSensorChanged invocation as timestamp.

The `IntentService`, of course, implements a `SensorEventListener` and it's implemented as a `WakefulIntentService` using [CommonsWare cwac-wakeful](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful).

What's happening is that sensor reading task takes a very highly variable time and sometimes, `onSensorChanged` - which I guess works asynchronously once the sensor listener is registered - gets called even minutes later, when the `IntentService` instance which registered the sensor listener, has already ended and the listener listening (!) is a successive one.

This translates to a series of data readings overlapping and being inserted into Google Fit without any temporal order with respect to the original timed invocation of the `IntentService` measuring task.

Besides, this behaviour also causes an abnormal usage of the battery, since the heart rate sensor uses a couple of very bright leds and - unless unregistered - keeps staying active until, I guess, its hardware timeout.

I've tried to unregister the sensor listener inside the `IntentService` by calling a post delayed `Runnable` after a certain timeout (30 secs), but it's not working.

**My questions are:**

Is there a way, inside an `IntentService` or a `WakefulIntentService` to call the sensor `unregisterListener` after a certain delay preventing the thread to end, meanwhile? Or to clear the onSensorChanged queue somehow?

Alternatively: Is there a way to assign an univoque ID to a sensor listener at the moment of its registration? This way, inside the `onSensorChanged`, it would be possible to match the event against its originating `IntentService` invocation time and it could be - at least - possible to insert the readings in Google Fit with the right temporal order.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've implemented an IntentService which, using SensorManager, reads data from a heart rate sensor.

IMHO, that is not a proper use of `IntentService`. IMHO, `IntentService` is designed for transaction bits of work: disk I/O, database I/O, Web service calls, etc. It is not designed for work of indefinite duration.

> The IntentService, of course, implements a SensorEventListener and it's implemented as a WakefulIntentService using CommonsWare cwac-wakeful.

`WakefulIntentService` is **not** designed for doing work indefinitely.

> What's happening is that sensor reading task takes a very highly variable time and sometimes, onSensorChanged - which I guess works asynchronously once the sensor listener is registered - gets called even minutes later, when the IntentService instance which registered the sensor listener, has already ended and the listener listening (!) is a successive one.

In general, there is no guarantee that you will get any sensor readings, as your process can terminate at any time once the service is destroyed.

> Is there a way, inside an IntentService or a WakefulIntentService to call the sensor unregisterListener after a certain delay preventing the thread to end, meanwhile?

Not in any reliable fashion.

Get rid of the `WakefulIntentService`. Use a regular `Service`. Register for sensor events. When you get the event(s) that you want, unregister the sensor listener and `stopSelf()` the service. Along the way, manage your own `WakeLock`.

> Or to clear the onSensorChanged queue somehow?

Not that I am aware of.

> Is there a way to assign an univoque ID to a sensor listener at the moment of its registration?

The listener object is already unique. Why would an ID make it more unique?

That being said, you are welcome to put a field in your listener object that has whatever sort of unique value that you like.

Comment: Thank you. I'm implementing a Service, started by a WakefulBroadcastReceiver. Where do you suggest i acquire and release the wake lock? Acquire in onCreate and release in onDestroy or I do release it immediately after the stopSelf in the onSensorChanged? Thanks!

Comment: @Veertualia: "Where do you suggest i acquire and release the wake lock?" -- off the cuff, I would acquire a reference-counted `WakeLock` in `onStartCommand()` (and there release the `WakeLock` from the `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`). Then, release the `WakeLock` as part of your `stopSelf()` processing. You can look at my `WakefulIntentService` for inspiration, even though it's not a direct solution.

Comment: I did as you said. Now the Runnable works and I can set a timeout before unregistering the listener, so I can stop the sensor when it's taking too long and there are no more overlapping onSensorChanged. Just perfect. How can I give you proper credit @CommonsWare ?

Comment: @Veertualia: I am glad that things are working for you. On Stack Overflow, if an answer answers your question, check the checkmark to the side of the question, thereby accepting it.